# sed output blank in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file which consists of following hundred lines in addition to other data

```
(abc-wxyz1/2222 1234)
```

1234 is a random number which is different for all the 100 lines. I want to substitute all the lines with

```
(abc-wxyz1/2222 *)
```

I am using following code for it

```
 cat input.txt | \
     sed -i -e 's/\(abc\-wxyz1\/2222\ [0-9]\+\)/\(abc\-wxyz1\/2222\ \*\)/g' > output.txt
```

I get the output.txt blank I have no clue why. Am I doing it correctly ?

Comment: The `-i` flag works differently on different versions of sed.  Different platforms use different versions.  What platform are you on?  Linux, Unix, Mac?  That said, the answer by rubens points out the first thing you need to change.

Comment: That's good news.  The linux version tends to be the easiest to work with (in my opinion).

Comment: FYI, "-e" is useless as you only have one command to execute.

Comment: Have you considered that are you asking sed to edit in place the stdin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use the flag `-i, --in place`, you don't have to redirect the output. The substitutions are performed *in place*, as expected.

Yet, you can simplify your expression, doing:

```
sed -i -e 's/abc\-wxyz1\/2222\ \([0-9]\+\)/*/g' input.txt
```

Comment: `-i` works differently on different versions of sed.  Sometimes you _must_ specify a backup extension.  Sometimes you don't hvae to... depends on the version of sed.

Comment: @jahroy I didn't know that; thanks for the info. Yet, there was no need to either `cat` the file, or redirect the output -- in case his version interprets `-i` as *in place*.

Comment: Yep, you're right: the redirect is the first thing he needs to fix.  Just figured I'd mention the `-i` thing in case it comes up as the next issue ;-)

Comment: ... but you need to specify a file name, not pipe from a ([useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)) `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

For the input sample you've shown, you could go with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1 " *)"}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to see what will be the result of filter:

```
cat input.txt | sed 's/\(abc\-wxyz1\/2222\ [0-9]\+\)/\(abc\-wxyz1\/2222\ \*\)/g'
```

Try using shorter patterns to toubleshoot where it is breaking.

You only need the '-e' flag if you have additional commands to run. You could also just do:

```
sed 'command;command2;{command3}'
```